# Understanding Pointers and Relationships to Structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is part of a study guide at the moment and while I realize its not very difficult, I can't understand what its asking for.

Write a Function:
struct *grump(int i, int j)
which returns a pointer to a "struct grump" holding the values i, j in its fields a,b

So Im given

```
struct grump
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

I'm just confused as to what its asking for

Comment: Did that study guide make any assertions as to whether you'll be allocating this structure dynamically with malloc() or some such?

Comment: My compiler is also confused. Perhaps you are asked to write a function `struct grump *gr(int i, intj) { };` returning a ptr to `struct grump;`

Comment: What I typed up there was the entire question. It was meant to be a simple example involving stucts and pointers. I just drawing a blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's asking you to allocate a `struct grump` that will hold the values `i` and `j`, something like:

```
struct grump* func(int i, int j)
{
    struct grump *g = malloc(sizeof(*g));
    if (g != NULL) {
       g->a = i;
       g->b = j;
    }
    return g;
}
```

Note: we check if `g != NULL` to make sure `malloc()` succeeded before using `grump` if not the function will return `NULL`. Of course at some point you will need to `free()` that memory, I'm sure your study guide will mention it soon.

Comment: thanks. I don't know why I was hung up on this haha. too much cramming .

Comment: Check that g is not NULL before using it

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a function 
Which will set the values you passed into function into the `struct grump` but it depends where is your struct object.

You can access the struct object if that is global or you are allocating using `malloc()`

I have shown demo using `malloc()`

You can do like this :

```
struct grump* foo(int i, int j)
{
struct grump *ptg;
ptg=malloc(sizeof(struct grump));
if(ptg)
{
ptg->a=i;
ptg->b=j;
}
return ptg;
}

int main()
{
struct grump *pg;
pg=foo(5,10);
// Do whatever you want 
free(pg); // Don't forget to free , It's best practice to free malloced object
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in things called *constructors* in C but that's essentially what you are writing.  It might be a good idea to take it to the next level and use `typedef` to create some slightly more object-like structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int a, b;
} g;

g *grump(int i, int j) {
  g *t = malloc(sizeof(g));
  t->a = i;
  t->b = j;
  return t;
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  g *a;

  a = grump(123, 456);
  printf("%d %d\n", a->a, a->b);
  return 0;
}
```